# Is there a way to easily spot unopened chests?

Tags: genshin-impact

I was looking at the Genshin Impact trophies I had left, and most of them are 'Open 100/200/300/400 chests in the Area'

I did not note which chests I did or not open; so having a map that gives me all of the chests is not that usefull. Especially since chests dissapear after being opened, so I might miss a chest because its on the map, but it was just somewhere I missed (like underground)

So is there a way to locate unopened chests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [Treasure Compass gadgets](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Treasure_Compass) that show you the direction of nearby chests when activated. Their blueprints are unlocked as reputation rewards for each region.

[image: Electro Treasure Compass gadget]

The best way to use these is together with an interactive map. You go where a chest is supposed to be, engage the Compass, and follow it to a chest. You mark off what you find on the map, and if the Compass indicates no chest nearby, you can assume you took that marker already. You can sweep areas for missed chests relatively quickly like this.

I recommend the [AppSample map](https://genshin-impact-map.appsample.com/) for this. It's unofficial, but allows (extremely useful) user comments.

Do note that:

- The Compasses can only detect chests that already exist in the world. Chests that pop into existence when you solve a puzzle or a mechanism are not detected.
- There is no Compass that works in Dragonspine, so the only way to find chests there is the hard way. I.e. visit every single chest marker on the map and try to figure out if you already took it with info from the user comments.